# How can I accsess the data attribute in plugin code?

Tags: firebreath

this is the tag the plugin uses `<object type="something" data="myfile.mytype"></object>`.
now I want to use the src value in my plugin source code, how can I access that?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    std::string test = m_host->getDOMElement()->getProperty<std::string>("src");
} catch (...) {
    // There wasn't a value to fetch
}
```